# Display custom column in Invoice grid using join

Tags: magento2, ui-grid, sales-invoice

I have custom moudule with custom table and tried to join it with invoice grid table to show it in invoice grid.But it is not working as it should.Here is what i have tried.

`adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

`collection.php`

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $myInvoiceTable = $this->getTable('mytable');
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ["myinv" => $myInvoiceTable],
            'main_table.entity_id = my.invoice_id',
            ['increment_id_with_prefix']
        )
           ;

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }


}
```

`sales_order_invoice_grid.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_invoice_columns">
        <column name="increment_id_with_prefix">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Invoice Increment</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`Mytable Structure`

[image: My Table Structure]

`Output invoice grid` It show some column missing data also not showing mytable column data.Also there is many invoice but it show only these 4 row only.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is working fine.Don't know why was not working with adding my custom argument class `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection`

`adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <plugin name="sales_invoice_additional_columns_for_gst" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SalesInvoiceGridCollection" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

`SalesInvoiceGridCollection.php`

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection;

class SalesInvoiceGridCollection
{
    const SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE = 'sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source';

    private $collection;

    public function __construct(SalesOrderInvoiceGridCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->collection = $collection;
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(CollectionFactory $subject, \Closure $proceed, $requestName)
    {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);

        if (self::SALES_ORDER_INVOICE_GRID_DATA_SOURCE == $requestName) {
            if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
                $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
                $select->joinLeft(
                    ["myinv" => 'mytable'],
                    'main_table.entity_id = myinv.invoice_id',
                    ['increment_id_with_prefix']
                );

                return $this->collection;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```